# How to combine the two JS of two select html tag with same functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select html tag. The values of each select option html tag have different array. I want to combine the two `var selectBox and the two Jquery since the functions are the same, but with different "id".

How to do this? It is possible?

HTML:

```
<select id="textlist">
    <option value="" selected><option>
</select>
<select id="placelist">
    <option value="" selected><option>
</select>
```

Select html tag 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#textlist').change(function(){
    jQuery('.texts').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
    });
});

var options = [
    { "text" : "Text 1", "value" : "Text1" },
    { "text" : "Text 2", "value" : "Text2" }
];

var selectBox = document.getElementById('textlist');
for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){
    var option = options[i];
    selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
}

jQuery("#placelist").html(jQuery("#placelist option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

Select html tag 2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#placelist').change(function(){
    jQuery('.places').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
    });
});

var options = [
    { "text" : "Place 1", "value" : "Place1" },
    { "text" : "Place 2", "value" : "Place2" }
];

var selectBox = document.getElementById('placelist');
for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){
    var option = options[i];
    selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
}

jQuery("#placelist").html(jQuery("#placelist option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

Comment: Hi, what's your intention with it? Is only refactoring? I didn't understand very well, tell me more about your idea.

Comment: I want to reuse the js in the 2nd select html tag

Answer (score 1):

Try making a function to reuse the code, as I've done below:

```
fucntion addOptions(id, className, options){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('#'+id).change(function(){
        jQuery('.'+className).hide();
        jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
        });
    });

    var selectBox = document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){
        var option = options[i];
        selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
    }

    jQuery("#"+id).html(jQuery("#"+id+" option").sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }))
}

var placeOptions = [
    { "text" : "Text 1", "value" : "Text1" },
    { "text" : "Text 2", "value" : "Text2" }
];

addOptions('placelist', 'places', placeOptions);

var textOptions = [
    { "text" : "Place 1", "value" : "Place1" },
    { "text" : "Place 2", "value" : "Place2" }
];

addOptions('textlist', 'texts', textOptions);
```

Comment: the values of select is not displaying

Comment: Can you create a sample in Jsfiddle? so I'll be able to see the problem.

Comment: also how to hide the results of option from select html tag 1, if the select html tag 2 has a selected option?

Comment: ok i found the problem, it is that i used the saved word class,i changed it to className . check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/tcz7x3z0/1/

Comment: yes but the results of each option tag is displayed even if there's no selected option

Comment: I didn't quite understand what isn't working right now

Comment: the results of selected option is displaying even there's no/before selected option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111608/discussion-between-sagi-levi-and-user014019).